# A symbol like a hourglass

Tags: symbols

What is the name of the following symbol and how to type it in LATEX?

Thanks!

[image: the symbol]

Comment: In `mdsymbol` package there is a $\hourglass$... Is it ok for you? Try it!

Comment: Thanks! I tried $\hourglass$, but this symbol is not compatible with other math symbols, for example $\sigma$, in terms of the size and weight.

Comment: Where do you want to use it? may be a change on fontsize like {\footnotesize $\hourglass$}$\cdot \sigma$ can do your job

Comment: I found also \upbowtie... but it is the same...

Comment: The weight can be changed with the `mdsymbol` package option `normalweight=Light`. Size can also be scaled up via the package option `size=1.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myhg}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\@hgpic}{\ensuremath{\sigma}}}}% Or \Sigma, or any symbol you want to scale to.
\newcommand{\@hgpic}{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.34cm}% reduce this to increase thickness of line
    \begin{picture}(1,1.5)%
    \thicklines%
    \put(0,0){\line(2,3){1}}%
    \put(1,1.5){\line(-1,0){1}}%
    \put(0,1.5){\line(2,-3){1}}%
    \put(1,0){\line(-1,0){1}}%
    \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    $\sigma a \myhg b$
    \[\sigma a \myhg b\]
\end{document}
```

## Drawing the symbol and varying the size

It's a simple affair to draw the hourglass using `picture`, then using the `scalerel` package to scale the symbol to the `\sigma` symbol (change this to whatever fits your use case).

## Varying the thickness of line

If you would like to make the lines thicker, you can reduce the `unitlength` slightly (not too much though).

## Spacing around the symbol

Also, note the spacing that should go around your hourglass symbol. I follow the convention of `mdsymbol`'s `\hourglass`/`\upbowtie`symbol and declared it as a binary operator, hence the `\mathbin`. You can remove it if you are intending to use it as a letter like `\sigma`.

[image]

Comment: +1 but I think the line width has to be fatter... And it would be better to keep both your old answer with \Sigma and the new one with both photos of the symbols because I don't know if it was too big or too small for him the symbol I found...

Comment: Thanks, added some extra notes. Since OP mentioned `\sigma` I'll keep it as the small letter for now :) OP's use case is not really clear so alot of it is just assumed. (+1 to your ans too -- quite creative)

Comment: Thanks... It is not really creative... Just used the symbols I found and rottated some of them because the most of them had fall down :P . I didn't want to draw, just to show him that all the existing symbols are the same size and he have probably to resize (or draw like your answer.) But in his comment he said it is not compatible... And this word doesn't mean it is not the same size as \sigma... May be he means it is too small next to this \sigma... This is the reason I told you to keep both answers. (A too small integral symbol is also not "compatible" with a F(x)dx... )

Answer (score 4):

All the ways (by using existing symbols) I found next to a \sigma:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mdsymbol}
\usepackage{allrunes}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\sigma$
\item $\sigma$ $\hourglass$ %mdsymbol
\item $\sigma$ $\upbowtie$ %mdsymbol
\item $\sigma$ \tikz \node [inner sep=0,rotate=90]{$\lrtimes$};%mdsymbol
\item $\sigma$ \tikz \node [inner sep=0,rotate=90]{$\Join$};%mdsymbol
\item $\sigma$ \tikz \node [inner sep=0,rotate=90]{\textara{d}}; %allrunes
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could also to use a similar code which is loaded with `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec`, where you can replace the respective hourglass code unicode instead of the asterisk (*) (for example of the type "211E).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{quivira.otf}
\renewcommand{\hourglass}{{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{*}}}
\begin{document}
\hourglass
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate `\bowtie`; depending on the nature of the symbol, you may want to use `\mathbin` (operation) instead of `\mathrel` (relation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hourglass}{}% preempt
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hourglass}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\hour@glass\relax}}

\newcommand\hour@glass[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\m@th#1\bowtie$}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\hourglass \sigma < B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If it's too big, you can scale it a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hourglass}{}% preempt
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hourglass}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\hour@glass\relax}}

\newcommand\hour@glass[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\m@th#1\bowtie$}}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\hourglass \sigma < B$

\end{document}
```

[image]